# Access Virtual Directory in Another Web Application

Tags: asp.net, directory, virtual

I have two web application projects (project A and project B) in the same solution.

I want to be able to: through project A, save a file somewhere in the directory of project B.

Whenever I use Server.MapPath etc, it resolves to the virtual directory of project A, not of B.

From my reading, I believe I should be able to type the URL of project B directly into the save method. However, neither project is deployed at the moment. Besides, I want to leverage the fact that they are on the same solution.

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But if you're *saving a file*, then you don't want to access the *virtual directory*; you want the **actual (physical) directory**.  That means *Request.MapPath* is the way to go; you can use the overload with *[cross-app mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z2189ck)* set to *true*.

```
string pathToAppB = Request.MapPath("/AppBVirtualPath", Request.ApplicationPath, true);
```

You still have to know which virtual path application B will be deployed to, though; and you can't test locally unless you deploy to your local IIS.

Comment: thanks for your reply. :) when you say i have to know app B's virtual path, does that mean the whole thing starting with the http? i guess what i'm really concerned about is that other developers working on the same solution on their own  machines (we're just using tortoise svn) might have app B deployed on a different virtual directory than on my machine. hope that was clear, i'm not really good at explaining :)

Answer (score 0):

You can config virtual directory of Project A and Project B to the same directory on your disk. When you save files from project A using Server.MapPath, it will be saved to that folder. Then when Project B tries to access the file via url. Virtual directory will access to the same directory.

To config virtual directory for web project:

In visual studio: see [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/msbuild/thread/758bec00-7ded-4312-af60-61beaaedac58).

In IIS: see [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk103ab.aspx).